# ReactJS: Can I create my own SyntheticEvent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using ReactJS and it's SyntheticEvent to track the event and it's target DOM node.

I am creating a few mutable components and I want them to fire SyntheticEvent to track the DOM and to track the changed value using `e.target` and `e.target.value`.

How can I instantiate SyntheticEvent and assign them DOM and it's target value?

Comment: Why do you need to use an event? If you have a reference to the DOM element already, can you just call a function? Use callbacks and pass the callbacks from parent to child as props.

Comment: I have an on-off switch which I want to work like checkbox and there does not exist any checkbox and I want to mimic it's behavior and so I want a SyntheticEvent. Same with my own WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 14):

I've created a helper function to make SyntheticEvent from Event:

```
export const createSyntheticEvent = <T extends Element, E extends Event>(event: E): React.SyntheticEvent<T, E> => {
  let isDefaultPrevented = false;
  let isPropagationStopped = false;
  const preventDefault = () => {
    isDefaultPrevented = true;
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  const stopPropagation = () => {
    isPropagationStopped = true;
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
  return {
    nativeEvent: event,
    currentTarget: event.currentTarget as EventTarget & T,
    target: event.target as EventTarget & T,
    bubbles: event.bubbles,
    cancelable: event.cancelable,
    defaultPrevented: event.defaultPrevented,
    eventPhase: event.eventPhase,
    isTrusted: event.isTrusted,
    preventDefault,
    isDefaultPrevented: () => isDefaultPrevented,
    stopPropagation,
    isPropagationStopped: () => isPropagationStopped,
    persist: () => {},
    timeStamp: event.timeStamp,
    type: event.type,
  };
}
```

That's an example of how I use it. I need to fire a change event, providing new value for the target. You can use it like this:

```
const target = document.createElement('input');
target.value = newValue;
const event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', { writable: false, value: target })
const syntheticEvent = createSyntheticEvent(event) as React.ChangeEvent<typeof target>;
onChange(syntheticEvent);
```

Saying that, please also consider "classic" way of triggering events by creating `new Event` and dispatching it to the HTML element (which you can access with
`inputRef.current`, where inputRef is defined as `inputRef = useRef()` and used as `<input ref={inputRef}`).

Answer (score 4):

In current state no, I was looking for all resources about SyntethicEvent to make sure and didn't find the API which used to create new SyntethicEvent, any way you can try to use native `addEventListener` on element's ref.
P.s. If you found the API which will provide the solution for your question, please share with us :)

Answer (score -7):

in the JSX your component returns you could add something like this

```
<button onClick={this.myEventHandlerFunc}>button text</button>
```

Declare the myEventHandlerFunc: function(e){} in your component and do your stuff :)

Hope this helped... I am starting to google now to find some extra examples ;)

EDIT:

If you want to fire custom events you could also just use JQuery for example and do the binding of those your events on the lifecycle event componentDidMount. here you could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('myCrazyEvent', this.componentEvtHandler)
```

Somewhere else you could create and distribute an event like this

```
$(document).trigger('myCrazyEvent', [customVar]);
```